# CSS Style all classes starting with string

Tags: css

I have a plugin that's automatically creating class names with a different number at the end.

```
.huge_it_slideshow_description_text_1
.huge_it_slideshow_description_text_2
.huge_it_slideshow_description_text_7
```

etc...

I need to style them all so I've added this css:

```
.huge_it_slideshow_description_text_ {
    styling here...
}
```

Is the syntax I'm using right?

Comment: If it works, then it's right. It it doesn't work, then it's wrong. Does it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [attribute starts with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selector

```
[class^="huge_it_slideshow_description_text_"] {
    styling here...
}
```

```css
[class^="huge_it_slideshow_description_text_"] {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="huge_it_slideshow_description_text_1">text</div>
<div class="normal-class">text</div>
<div class="huge_it_slideshow_description_text_2">text</div>
<div class="huge_it_slideshow_description_text_3">text</div>
```

Comment: Damn..beaten by 5 seconds

Comment: @Tushar, click the link in my answer. It is pure css

Comment: @Tushar, also, see the snippet in my answer

Comment: @AmmarCSE Learned new thing today

Comment: @Tushar, we all do :)